# Can I safely pressure can potato soup with milk in it?

Tags: food-preservation

Can I safely pressure can potato soup with milk in it?  I made potato soup and would like to can it for later use. Problem is I already put milk in it.  Do I have any alternative ways to preserve it?  I had 20 lbs.of potatoes I had to do something with before they went bad!

Comment: Freezing the soup will certainly preserve it in a *safe* manner... question is whether it will freeze well. You can try with a small amount, keeping the rest chilled ....

Answer (score 3):

According to USDA [National Center for Home Food Preservation](http://nchfp.uga.edu/how/can_04/soups.html), no:

> Caution: Do not add noodles or other pasta, rice, flour, cream, milk or other thickening agents to home canned soups. If dried beans or peas are used, they must be fully rehydrated first.

From [Penn State Extension](http://extension.psu.edu/food/preservation/news/2012/making-soup-safely):

> ...there are some commercially prepared foods that just cannot be reproduced safely by the home canner. Creamed soups are not suitable for home canning because their ingredients interfere with the proper transfer of heat during the processing step and can result in food borne illness.

From BUTTER AND MILK…WHY CAN’T THEY BE CANNED?
By Ruth Woods
UCCE El Dorado County Master Food Preservers

> Look no further than a post by Dr. Elizabeth L. Andress, National Director of Home
>   Food Preservation, University of Georgia Department of Foods and Nutrition. Dr.
>   Andress, a Professor and Extension Food Safety Specialist, commented on several
>   questions posed regarding the safety of home canning soups that contained butters and
>   milks. According to Dr. Andress, there are no established safe procedures for canning
>   dairy products. She echoed the stance that many personal internet sites that share
>   canning recipes and information pose safety concerns: For a recipe to be safe, it needs to
>   be thoroughly challenged in microbiology studies to confirm a safe product is achieved
>   every time it is processed. Dr. Andress further explained that the “amount of heat that
>   would have to be applied to kill harmful bacteria” that grows in dairy products in a
>   processed jar held at room temperature would be “extremely detrimental to its quality.”
>   She went on to say that, “Milk is a finely balanced emulsion of proteins in water. If the
>   proteins are over-heated, they drop out of suspension and the milk separates.

There are commercially canned foods that contain dairy, but they use processes that are not available to home canners. To be safe, do not use dairy in recipes that will be canned at home.

Comment: I was going to ask if this applied to pressure canning, too ... but looking at the first link makes it pretty obvious that they considered that (as it's only talking about pressure canning).